# How to change text in jQuery and reset original text after 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I want to change a list item with the id & title `Save` to `Saved` when the user clicks on that list item. Then, after 5 seconds, I want `Saved` to revert back to `Save`. I am not concerned with how it changes, whether it fades out or other.

I have tried unsuccessfully with `setTimeout`. Is that the correct approach?

Answer (score 4):

You should really show what you have tried so far. That said, the below will work for your needs:

```js
$('#save').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var originalText = $this.text();
  $this.text('Saved');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $this.text(originalText)
  }, 5000); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="save">Save</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, apologies for not putting the code, it's my first time posting here and wasn't sure how! Anyway, thanks very much! Your code worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 3):

Something simple like this I prefer to do in pure JS as I like to milk a little bit of extra speed here and there by not calling jQuery functions when I don't have to. Here is a vanilla JS example if you like.

```
document.getElementById('saved').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.textContent = 'Saved';

    setTimeout(function() {
        self.textContent = 'Save';
    }, 5000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0sdc5r9a/

Comment: Your first sentence could have been the comment without a downvote. Either way I edited the post to remove the variable. Nothing wrong with caching variables if you're going to use it again for other events, but in this case Delighted is correct if not re-using it.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a bit of code I think that it will gonna help you to solve your problem or I guess you already did because this question is 6 years ago like oh my that's so long 
but I guess that it may help you

**HTML Code**

So at here create a dropdown select list

```
<p>Select Item</p>
  <select>
    <option>Laptop</option>
    <option>Mouse</option>
    <option>Keyboard</option>
    <option>Mobile</option>
    </select>
<p id="pra">Save</p>
```

**JQuery Code**

Make a function here and in this function write the text as when you click you will get the text shown in your browser or document. And add `setTimeout`(which is obviously will be in `camelCased` to set the timing and also set what do you wanna do after how many times.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#pra").on("click", function(){
   setTimeout(function(){$("#pra").html("Saved!"); });
   setTimeout(function(){$("#pra").html("Save"); }, 5000)
  });
});
```

**Hope It Helps & Solves Your Problem :)**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can keep the original text with the element when changing the text so that during reverting back you don't need to put it as static string.
The code is as following:

```
$('.list-item').on('click', function() {
    var itemEl = $(this);
        itemEl.data('originalText', $(this).html());
        itemEl.html('Saved');

        setTimeout(function() { 
            itemEl.html(itemEl.data('originalText')) }, 5000);
  });
```

Check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0vjge88w/)

Comment: There is no reason to use a data attribute here. You can simply declare a variable to hold the text itself then use that variable in the settimeout function which will still have access to it when it is fired

Comment: Yes, that could have implemented using a variable, but I just tried to show the way because there are lot of situation when you change the button text in a function and you revert it back to the original text on different function depending on some other events/actions. Then how will you do with a variable? And the above state situation is very common.

Comment: I know that very well but you should answer what is  the best solution keeping the general situations in mind, right?

Comment: Sure, but adding a completely useless and unnecessary function based on assumed possible future requirements not stated or implied by the OP in no represents 'the best solution'